# Test for change in month from list of dates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to code something in VBA that could identify each time there's a change in month, for example from January to February.

In the below example you can see I want to take the input from column B, and output to column C. The output should be:

- `Test` when a month change occurs.
- `Train` when the month is the same as before.

Example data:

```
A       B              C
1       29/12/2006     Train    
2       01/01/2007     Test    
3       02/01/2007     Train    
4       03/01/2007     Train    
5       04/01/2007     Train    
6       05/01/2007     Train
..   
100     01/07/2007     Test
```

Comment: The `Month` formula? You don't need VBA.

Comment: or `day`=1 if that remains throughout

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably do the job:

`=IF(And(Month(A4)=Month(A3);Year(A4)=Year(A3));"Train";"Test")`

It compares months for A4 and A3 and the years.

Comment: Don't think you even need to check the year do you?

Comment: @SJR, well, depends on the data you are given.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.  `A1-Day(A1)` will always return the last day of the preceding month.  So:

```
B2:  =IF((A1-DAY(A1))=(A2-DAY(A2)),"Train","Test")
```